# Suddenly all emails in User have [email protected]

Tags: users, email

I don't know what happened but suddenly all emails under "User" are changed to `[email protected]` - see the below picture.

Of course, my first thought was a plugin problem, but when I disable **ALL** plugins then nothing changes.

Any idea what happened? The site is running under Cloudflare for months but this issue does exist since few days.

I am not aware of anything I could have changed. I am viewing the users as administrator.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is coming from cloudflare's Email Address Obfuscation.

1. Login to Cloudflare.
2. Click on your domain name.
3. Navigate to Scrape Shield
4. Turn off Email Address Obfuscation.
5. Purge Cloudflare Cache

[image]

Comment: +1! Very strange. Cloudflare must have had added it few days ago. I had to purge also the cache but it fixed it! Thx!

Comment: Good thought on purging cache!

Answer (score 0):

Cloudflare has added [Configuration Rules](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/configuration-rules/) where you can set which pages you want to disable settings for.
As Haris pointed out, Email Address Obfuscation is causing the reported issue, but with these new rules you don't have to globally disable the feature. You simply add a URI based configuration rule to disable the feature.